# Is testing for interface implementation good design?

Tags: c#

I have a rather general question. Is it good or bad design to have several classes that might implement a common interface but have nothing else in common and to test whether the interface is implemented to perform some action?

Example: A `Builder` object can be configured externally with an instance of a subclass of `Something`. Some of these subclasses have a special `BuildCommand` method, some don't. If the current `Something` doesn't have a `BuildCommand` method, `Builder` should employ a default `BuildCommand` method defined in `Target` class.

I'm not quite sure if my solution would be considered good or bad design. I'd appreciate your opinions.

Thank you a lot,
Fabian

```
public interface ICommandBuilder
{
    ICommand BuildCommand();
}

public class Something1 : Something
{
    /* ... */
}
public class Something2 : Something, ICommandBuilder
{
    /* ... */
}

public class Target : ICommandBuilder
{
    /* ... */
}

public class Builder
{
    public Something Something { get; set; }

    public Target CreateTarget()
    {
        var target = new Target();

        /* Some code to configure target */

        var commandBuilder = (Something as ICommandBuilder) ?? Target;
        target.AddCommand(commandBuilder.BuildCommand());

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid names such as `Something1`, `Something2`, etc. It is a real pain to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `ICommandBuilder` then use property of `ICommandBuilder` type, that will make your dependency clear:

```
public class TargetBuilder
{
    public ICommandBuilder CommandBuilder { get; set; }
    public Something Something { get; set; }

    public Target CreateTarget()
    {
        var target = new Target();    
        /* Some code to configure target */

        var commandBuilder = CommandBuilder ?? target;
        target.AddCommand(commandBuilder.BuildCommand());

        return target;
    }
}
```

You can assign same instance of object both to `Something` and `CommandBuilder` properties. Having two different properties for two different purposes looks clear to me. There is no **hidden feature** of checking if `Something` implements `ICommandBuilder`.

You even can create constructor, which will accept type which implements both `Something` and `ICommandBuilder` to simplify assigning of both properties:

```
public TargetBuilder()
{
}

public TargetBuilder(Something2 something2)
   : this(something2, something2)
{
}

public TargetBuilder(Something something, ICommandBuilder commandBuilder)
{
    Something = something;
    CommandBuilder = commandBuilder;
}
```

Comment: No, Something does a lot more. The BuildCommand method is a rather tiny part of the class.

Comment: @fdub that's why I wrote about assigning same instance to both properties

Comment: The Something instance is created by deserializing an xml file. Using your suggestion, I can't know which subclass it is and I have to do an explicit type or interface check again to set the CommandBuilder property. And I also can't use the explicit subclasses as they are constantly changing (some are removed, some are added).

Comment: @fdub you specified your question as *rather general* without mentioning any xml deserialization. I provided rather general code, which I would use

Comment: @fdub speaking about deserialization, I'd propbably check whether deserialized Something implements ICommandBuilder before assigning it to TargetBuilder

Comment: Sergey, only the example was rather specific, the question itself was meant general. Maybe it was not the best example to show the problem. What I didn't like about my implementation was exactly the **hidden feature** (thanks for the term!) if some of the subclasses implement `ICommandBuilder` and some don't. One can't know that `Something` might be related to `ICommandBuilder` without knowing all subclasses... And I like the idea of a `CommandBuilder` property and will try to find a way to implement it. Thanks.